# Splash-screen с векторной картинкой, как указать отступы

Tags: android, vector

Здравствуйте, небольшой опыт использования векторных изображений.
Захотел сделать splash-screen(экран при загрузке). Создал тему в 
style, повесил на фон у SplashActivity:

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>
</style>
```

xml:

```
<item
    android:drawable="@color/grey"/>

<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/ice_cream"
    android:gravity="center" >

</item>
```

Вектор:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:viewportWidth="6688"
    android:viewportHeight="6688"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="36dp">
```

Изображение svg и оно растягивается на весь экран. Цель центрировать его с приемлемым размером. Неужели я смогу добиться нужного эффекта только с нарезанным PNG?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: поставьте падинги контейнеру или маржины виджету (в xml это атрибут <inset>)

Answer (score 0):

меняя следующие параметры можно отцентровать картинку, как вы хотите

```
android:viewportWidth="6688"
android:viewportHeight="6688"
```

при этом не забывайте менять масштаб и в этих полях:

```
android:width="24dp"
android:height="36dp"
```